# Ubuntu 13.04 The following packages have unmet dependenies

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Whenever I try to install anything on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-mesa-drivers : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be    installed
                    Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I follow the advice and do

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Then I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-client0_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.1.0', which is also in package libwayland0:amd64 1.0.5-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already Unpacking libwayland-server0:amd64 (from .../libwayland-server0_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-server0_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0.0.0', which is also in package libwayland0:amd64 1.0.5-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Can anyone help. I have already googled on this but could not find anything which helps me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu, try [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Please do not close. I have search askubuntu.com but none of the suggestions there worked for me. there also they close this question as duplicate and point to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies ... but this does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and searched the internet and every solution did not work for me.

I realized that the packaging system is broken for good. and I deleted the linux vm and recreated it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, it's not a fix for the issue you reported (on the wrong site as you were told).